# Find all of the packages installed and install them on another PC

Tags: opensuse

I want to install all the packages which I have on my PC in the office into the PC I've got at home.

Is there any way doing that using terminal?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should ask it at superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @stonedsquirrel thanks...next time, I'll do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get list of names (without version) of all installed packages use:

```
rpm -q -a --qf '%{NAME} ' > pkglist.txt
```

Than feed that list to zypper on another system:

```
zypper in `cat pkglist.txt`
```

Comment: thanks, does it check automatically for the dependencies as well?

Comment: Zypper does check and install dependencies automatically, but in this way you are specifying all dependencies as resolved on source system. You may get some warnings that some packages are already installed.